# searching deeper than 1 into json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

im trying to figure out how to search deeper than just one deep in my `JSON` file.

its structure is as follows

```
json>data>movies>
```

in movies the different movies are enumerated 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc so

```
json>data>movies>3>
```

would contain movie information for the 4th movie
each containing key value pairs.the code i am using only seems to look one deep, and i cant seem to get it to go deeper.

code is as follows

```
$('#search').keyup(function () { // i understand this to watch the form id search
    var searchField = $('#search').val(); // sets variable searchfield from typed content, .val grabs the content
    if (searchField.length) // this sets the length to false by default ensuring the code only runs when it is supposed to and not all the time
    {
        var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i"); // sets variable myexp to regular expression using "i" for case insensitive
        var found = 0; // sets variable found to 0 to keep div hidden until match is found
        $.getJSON('/secure/movies.json', function (data) { //gets movies.json file pushes to data function
            var output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
            $.each(data, function (key, val) { // this should make key pairs from data
                if (val.title.search(myExp) !== -1) { // this is the problem i think
                    console.log(val); // this should show our search term results in console
                    found = 1;
                    output += '<li>';
                    output += '<h2>' + val.title + '</h2>';
                    output += "<a href=" + val.image + ' target="_blank" ></a>';
                    output += '</li>';
                }
            });
            output += '</ul>';
            if (found == 1) {
                $('#update').removeClass('update-hidden');
                $('#update').html(output);
            } else {
                $('#update').addClass('update-hidden');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#update').addClass('update-hidden');
    }
});
```

ive tried manipulating val.title.search(myexp) but i might be missing the boat on whats happening here with val.title.search.  thanks in advance

Comment: What is `console.log(val)` showing?

Comment: Can you show what your JSON data looks like?

Comment: nothing in the console no errors.  heres a snippet of json. too big to post here [link]http://pastebin.com/C06fnrif @morrin